# OpenVPN 2.4 + Google Authenticator = authentication failure

Tags: openvpn, pam, ubuntu-18.04, google-authenticator

We have a corporate VPN server running OpenVPN 2.3 on an AWS instance with Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. The server has been configured using an Ansible playbook.

I'm planning to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, which also upgrades OpenVPN to version 2.4 (this is a desired side effect, as OpenVPN 2.3 is getting deprecated). So I created a test instance with Bionic on it, and ran the Ansible playbook against it. The configuration includes MFA through Google Authenticator, so I also copied `~/.google_authenticator` file from the old server and applied `chmod 400` to it.

There were also a couple of compatibility issues which I had to solved before the new server worked:

- `openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so` file location has changed, and now its full path doesn't need to be specified in the server config.
- `CAP_AUDIT_WRITE` permission missing in `openvpn` systemd service (see more details [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1511524))

However, even after that authentication still fails on the new server. Here's what my `/etc/pam.d/openvpn` looks like:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

If I replace this line with `auth required pam_permit.so`, I get successfully authenticated (with any password of course) and connected, so the problem is definitely where MFA steps in.

At the same time, `pamtester` tells me that `pam_google_authenticator.so` works fine:

```
$ sudo pamtester openvpn vlad authenticate
Verification code:
pamtester: successfully authenticated
```

Here's what I see in syslog when trying to authenticate to VPN server:

```
Aug 16 15:17:39 ip-10-7-0-230 openvpn[10873]: AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: received command code: 0
Aug 16 15:17:39 ip-10-7-0-230 openvpn[10873]: AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: USER: vlad
Aug 16 15:17:39 ip-10-7-0-230 openvpn[10873]: AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: my_conv[0] query='login:' style=2
Aug 16 15:17:39 ip-10-7-0-230 openvpn[10873]: AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: user 'vlad' failed to authenticate: Authentication failure
```

In [this thread](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam/issues/95#issuecomment-389014880) I found a suggestion that the line in server config that calls auth-pam module should be changed from

```
plugin openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
```

to:

```
plugin openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so "openvpn login USERNAME password PASSWORD"
```

However, neither of them seems to work - I still get "Authentication failure".

Interestingly, the same experiment with rebuilding the server on the base of Xenial worked - so the problem seems to be either in Ubuntu Bionic (some additional security features?) or in OpenVPN 2.4 (some compatibility issues).

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

*Update*. Just tried adding `nullok` to `/etc/pam.d/openvpn` and deleting `~/.google_authenticator` file. Still fails, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 and higher use a more strict sandboxing config in systemd which interferes with google-authenticator.

Simply edit `/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service` and remove this line:

```
[Service]
...
ProtectHome=true
```

This is a newer feature of systemd that makes directories with 'user' content in them appear empty, for example `/home`, `/root`, and `/run/user`

It's generally a good idea to enable this as `/home` often contains SSH and GPG keys, but in this case it prevents OpenVPN from reading the `.google-authenticator` file in the users' home directory.

More info:

- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/mastering-systemd
- https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam/issues/98

Comment: Thanks! I have no way to test your suggestion unfortunately, because we have already migrated away to a managed VPN solution, but since your answer looks plausible, and there haven't been any others within almost 3 years, I'm going to accept it.